# FFmpeg does not add query string parameter to subsequent request URL

Tags: ffmpeg

When processing HLS/Dash playlist *(where query-param used for auth)* - ffmpeg doesn't add those query-strings in data chunk requests, which results in 403 forbidden error form the server.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://example.com/playlist.m3u8?auth=foo" out.mp4
```

chunk request is like: `http://example.com/chunk1.ts` - instead of `http://example.com/chunk1.ts?auth=foo`

Is there any option to circumvent that or is it not supported, or a bug?

Comment: Is it _supposed to_ be supported? That is, does anything in HLS or DASH say that the client should copy URL parameters? I mean, it's something I would never expect to happen, as the query params aren't even copied across redirects, much less whole new URLs... (and if the parameters were important for authentication, I think the _server_ should generate a .m3u8 with them included).

Comment: @user1686 I agree, but [here](https://www.loom.com/share/0d13570c64fc46dabfc06b4a1f20f158), you'll find that query-params are added when chunk requests are sent from the browser. But not the same behavior in ffmpeg.

Comment: @Neeraj The example you gave is not HLS - it is a proprietary protocol inspired by HLS, but it does not use an M3U8 playlist, instead it generates the requests via JS from a template. This will obviously not work with FFmpeg, as it expects a true HLS stream

Comment: @EugenRieck Its DASH. I also mentioned HLS since ffmpeg behaves the same for both.

Comment: It's the same with DASH - if query parameters are necessary, they must be part of the chunk list.

Answer (score 2):

HLS works this way: The query string parameters (if any) are used to query the M3U8 chunklist, which in turn contains the URLs for the chunks. If these URLs from the chunklist (i.e. **that you have no control over**) do not contain query parameters, then none will be used to query them.

You can work around this by proxying the M3U8 through a web service you control, that adds the query parameters to the chunk list.

Comment: Had that idea already, but that's not very convenient. I wonder why ffmpeg not support this yet _(atleast w/ turn on/off option)_. Any caveats?

Comment: FFmpeg supports HLS and DASH - in both, the query parameters are NOT carried from the chunk list to the chunks. I know this is bad news for you, but it is just how these protocols are defined.